# Duvida validar .click() fora da function() jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Preciso validar se o `button` com a classe `.pop-yes` foi clicado, porém preciso validar isso fora do evento `.click()` para que a linha do código `$(this).parent [...]` seja executada.

Do jeito que está aqui, ela é executada antes de eu clicar no `.pop-yes` e, se eu coloco ela dentro da function `.click()`, ela simplesmente não é executada.

```
$(function() {
    // .delete recebe o id que devo deletar..
    $(".delete").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + id;

    $('.pop').fadeIn("slow");

    $('.pop-no').click(function(){
        $('.pop').fadeOut("slow");
    });

    //Aqui eu clico para confirmar o delete
    $('.pop-yes').click(function(){

        $('.pop').fadeOut("slow");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/removeClient",
            data: info,
            success: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });

    // aqui faz a row da table sumir sem carregar a página
    // porem eu só quero que ela seja executada caso o .pop-yes.click() seja true
    // Se eu coloco ela dentro da .pop-yes.click() ela não funciona acho que não encontra a #show
    $(this).parents("#show").animate({backgroundColor: "#003"}, "slow").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "slow");

    });
});
```

Parte do código `html`:

```
<tr id="show" class="tr_<?= $client['id'];?>">
     <td><?= $client['name']; ?></td>
     <td><?= $client['email']; ?></td>
     <td><?= $client['nickname']; ?></td>
     <td><?= $client['hour_value']; ?></td>
     <td><?= $client['discount']; ?></td>
     <td><?= $client['date_pagment']; ?></td>
     <td><?= $client['cep']; ?></td>
     <td class="text-center">
         <button id="<?= $client['id']; ?>" class="delete glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
     </td>
 </tr>

 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="pop">
    <div class="pop-up">
        <h4>Message <?= $client['name']; ?> </h4>
        <button class="btn btn-danger pop-no" >Não</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary pop-yes">Sim</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Que código executado antes é esse? E se é da maneira que está na pergunta, por quê não utiliza este código? Dá algum erro? Se sim, qual o erro? Seja mais claro na sua pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Cara é esta ultima linha $(this).parents ... ela é quem faz a linha da table que vai ser excluida sumir.. do jeito que esta ela some mesmo antes de eu confirmar a exclusão, porem se atualizo a página  ela volta.. se eu coloco ela dentro do evento .click() ela não funciona entende? já tentei fazer uma if fora do evento para validar.. mas não deu certo.. obrigado!

Comment: Creio que o problema é o `$(function() {});` se você remover ele seu código deve funcionar corretamente. Creio que da forma que está o navegador não vai interpretar corretamente.

Comment: @Knautiluz isso faz parte do jQuery e está correto desta forma. Drik, edite sua pergunta e coloque seu problema por completo, incluindo a parte do HTML e descreva exatamente o que quer fazer. Da maneira que está, seu código está, no mínimo, confuso.

Comment: A `.pop-yes.click` está dentro da `.delete.click`, está correto isso mesmo?

Comment: sim pois ela precisa receber os valores do id que vem da .delete

Comment: Editei a pergunta, tentei ser mais claro com minha duvida.. agradeço!

Comment: Onde está o elemento `.pop-yes`? Você provavelmente terá que jogar o código para dentro do evento `click` (se ele deve executar com o `click`, deve estar dentro deste evento), mas me parece que você só tentou recortar e colar o código para dentro da função, sem adaptá-la. Provavelmente terá que modificar a parte `$(this).patents`, pois o `this` mudará de referência.

Comment: Exato porem, dentro do elemento .click() as as var do .delete não são encontradas e o $this.parents() não executado.. fora ele executa do jeito certo mas executa antes do .pop-yes ser clicado, eu só queria uma forma de validar o .click() fora do evento ai funcionaria do jeito esperado, você me deixou mas confuso do que já estava, e não, não recortei e colei, apenas sou novato em ajax + jquery.. mas obrigado por tentar ajudar...!

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte (*script*):

```
 $(function() {

     // .delete recebe o id que devo deletar..
     $(".delete").click(function(){
          id = $(this).attr("id");
          info = 'id=' + id;

          $('.pop').fadeIn("slow");
     });

     $('.pop-no').click(function(){
         $('.pop').fadeOut("slow");
     });

     //Aqui eu clico para confirmar o delete
     $('.pop-yes').click(function(){

         $('.pop').fadeOut("slow");

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/removeClient",
             data: info,
             success: function () {
                 return true;
             }
         });

          // aqui faz a row da table sumir sem carregar a página
          // porem eu só quero que ela seja executada caso o .pop-yes.click() seja true
          // Se eu coloco ela dentro da .pop-yes.click() ela não funciona acho que não encontra a #show
          $(this).parents().animate({backgroundColor: "#003"}, "slow").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "slow");

     });


 });
```

*HTML*:

```
<div class="pop" style="display: none;">
    <div class="pop-up">
        <h4>Message <?= $client['name']; ?></h4>
        <button class="btn btn-danger pop-no" >Não</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary pop-yes">Sim</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: Não tem como eu testar sem o código completo. Fiz as alterações que acredito que vá funcionar. Utilize os comentários para sugerir alteração/correção.

Comment: Desse jeito a o efeito de .animate pegou na tela inteira em vez de ocultar a row deletada, ele apagou a tela inteira o #show é quem deve ser ocultado, tentei colocar ele no .parents("#show") mais não deu, parece que ele so encontra o #show com o id selecionado, quando esta na function do .delete...

Comment: Teste aí novamente, @Drik

Comment: Então brother, quando clico no sim ele apaga a tela inteira o registro é excluido, porem apaga a tela inteira, quando só deveria apagar o tr com id show ("#show")...

Comment: Vlw a ajuda ae brother, consegui resolver, postei ai a resposta pra ajudar quem precisar!

Answer (score 1):

Como a função do `.pop-no` é apenas de ocultar o elemento da classe `.pop`, você só precisa checar se `.pop` está sendo mostrado ou não quando clicar no `.pop-yes`.

Como checar? Use a função `is(':visible')` do jQuery, veja o exemplo abaixo e aplique-o ao seu exemplo.

```
$('.pop-yes').click(function() {
  //...//
  var popEstaVisivel = $('.pop').is(':visible');
  if (!popEstaVisivel)//checa se .pop não está visível
    $(this).parents("#show").animate({...});
});
```

Comment: Então.. o pop abre e fecha corretamente, o problema é que não apaga a linha da tabela deletada da forma esperada..

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente agradeço a todos que tentaram me ajudar, o problema foi resolvido da seguinte maneira:

```
$(function() {
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        id = $(this).attr("id");
        info = 'id=' + id;

        $('.pop').fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('.pop-yes').click(function(){

        $('.pop').fadeOut("slow");

        $('.delete').parents(".tr_"+ id).animate({backgroundColor: "#003"}, "slow").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "slow");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/removeClient",
            data: info
        });
    });

    $('.pop-no').click(function(){
        $('.pop').fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

Código html:

```
<tr class="tr_<?= $client['id'];?>">
    <td><?= $client['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $client['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $client['nickname']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $client['hour_value']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $client['discount']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $client['date_pagment']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $client['cep']; ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><button id="<?= $client['id']; ?>" class="delete glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button></td>
</tr>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="pop" style="display: none;">
    <div class="pop-up">
        <h4>Message <?= $client['name']; ?></h4>
        <button class="btn btn-danger pop-no" >Não</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary pop-yes">Sim</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Marque a resposta como aceita para encerar a pergunta

Comment: Eu não posso aceitar minha resposta em 2 dias.. rsrs